# PL/SQL Case Statement - IS NULL

Tags: plsql, case

I have some SQL, far too much to add all of the statement in this question, that I am trying to improve in order to drive out system slowdowns.

In part of the PL/SQL there is an **AND Exists** clause that contains an **AND Not Exists** clause.

Both of these clauses contain **Case** statements. After the **End** part of the case statement, there is either an **IS NOT NULL** or **IS NULL** statement.   Having used PL/SQL for some years this is the first time that I have seen this syntax and I freely admit to not understanding it.  The whole of the **AND Exists** clause is displayed below,  and help would be greatly appreciated.

```
AND EXISTS  (
  SELECT Distinct PROJECTID
  From Milestone_History MH, 
       Project_Milestone PM
  Where MH.MilestoneId = PM.ID
    AND MH.Projectid = PR.ID
    AND ((UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FINAL BUILD INVOICE INSTRUCTIONS ISSUED') OR
         (UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED') OR
         (UPPER(PM.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE'))
     AND (case when UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED' then
                  Actual
                End IS NOT NULL 

                AND 
                  case
                    when UPPER(PM.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE' then
                      MH.Actual
                  end IS NULL)
           AND NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT Distinct MH2.ProjectID
          From Milestone_History MH2, Project_Milestone PM2
          Where MH2.MilestoneId = PM2.ID
            And MH2.ProjectID = MH.ProjectID
            AND case
                    when UPPER(PM2.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE' then  -
                          MH2.Actual
                    end IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of the `CASE...END` as a single expression. You can use parentheses to get a better understanding:

```
(case when UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED' 
    then Actual
 End) IS NOT NULL
```

This particular expression is `NOT NULL` if and only if the `CASE` finds a match and `Actual` is not null.

This could be rewritten as:

```
(UPPER(pm.description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED'
AND actual IS NOT NULL)
```

The following statement could be rewritten as:

```
(UPPER(PM.Description) != 'PROJECT COMPLETE'
 OR PM.Description IS NULL
 OR actual IS NULL)
```

The two statements are clearly overlapping: `Descrition` can only have one value. When we merge them there is not much left:

```
(SELECT Distinct PROJECTID
   From Milestone_History MH, 
        Project_Milestone PM
  Where MH.MilestoneId = PM.ID
    AND MH.Projectid = PR.ID
    AND UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED'
    AND actual IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT Distinct MH2.ProjectID
            From Milestone_History MH2, Project_Milestone PM2
           Where MH2.MilestoneId = PM2.ID
             And MH2.ProjectID = MH.ProjectID
             AND PM2.Description = 'PROJECT COMPLETE'
             AND MH2.Actual IS NOT NULL)
)
```

I think it's a bit misleading to use `CASE` when there is a single case.

Either the author was misinformed about the behaviour of `CASE` or this is remnant code that has been updated along the way without being cleaned.

Comment: +1 GMTA :) I'm not sure whether to delete mine, or leave it as a slightly different way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @MarkBannister Clearly convergent explanations here =)

Answer (score 2):

The first two conditions:

```
 Where MH.MilestoneId = PM.ID
   AND MH.Projectid = PR.ID
```

- join the two tables in the subquery, and join the subquery to the main query.

The next three conditions:

```
AND (UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FINAL BUILD INVOICE INSTRUCTIONS ISSUED' OR
     UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED' OR
     UPPER(PM.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE')
```

- ensure that `Description` is one of three values.

However the next condition:

```
AND case when UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED' 
         then Actual End IS NOT NULL
```

- although OK in itself, contradicts two of the three previous conditions. An expression written as `CASE WHEN condition THEN value END IS NOT NULL` is essentially saying **both** that `condition` must be true (otherwise the CASE clause evaluates as NULL) **and** that value must not be NULL; it could be rewritten as:

```
AND UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED' 
AND Actual IS NOT NULL
```

- which is both clearer and more concise (and rules out two of the three conditions from the previous parenthesised clause).

The next condition:

```
AND case when UPPER(PM.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE' 
         then MH.Actual end IS NULL
```

- although (again) OK in itself, is essentially redundant due to the previous condition; it could be rewritten as:

```
AND (UPPER(PM.Description) <> 'PROJECT COMPLETE' OR MH.Actual IS NULL)
```

- again, both clearer and more concise. It is also unnecessary, since the previous condition `UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED'` ensures that `UPPER(PM.Description) <> 'PROJECT COMPLETE'` will always be true.

The `NOT EXISTS` clause could be included as a separate clause at the end of the main query outside the `EXISTS` clause, simply by changing `And MH2.ProjectID = MH.ProjectID` to
`And MH2.ProjectID = PR.ProjectID` - however, the query should execute a little faster with the `NOT EXISTS` clause inside the `EXISTS` clause, since it will only be evaluated if the rest of the `EXISTS` clause is true.

As with the previous IS NOT NULL condition, the expression:

```
  AND case when UPPER(PM2.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE' 
           then MH2.Actual end IS NOT NULL
```

- could be rewritten as:

```
  AND UPPER(PM2.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE' 
  AND MH2.Actual IS NOT NULL
```

So the whole clause could be rewritten as:

```
AND EXISTS 
(SELECT Distinct PROJECTID
 From Milestone_History MH, Project_Milestone PM
 Where MH.MilestoneId = PM.ID
   AND MH.Projectid = PR.ID
   AND UPPER(PM.Description) = 'FEASIBILITY STUDY REQUIRED' 
   AND Actual IS NOT NULL 
   AND NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT Distinct MH2.ProjectID
    From Milestone_History MH2, Project_Milestone PM2
    Where MH2.MilestoneId = PM2.ID
      AND UPPER(PM2.Description) = 'PROJECT COMPLETE' 
      AND MH2.Actual IS NOT NULL
   )
)
```